# Having issues with running aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yfinance

I am trying to get this stock data collector to work on AWS (https://github.com/JustinGuese/aws-lambda-stockdata-collector).I've followed the instructions and when ever I run the function I get error

```
    Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-02-02T11:32:24.018Z 18fecfde-318c-47a5-8df5-aa9bdbc6f138 Task timed out after 180.11 seconds"
}

Function Logs
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
running
START RequestId: 18fecfde-318c-47a5-8df5-aa9bdbc6f138 Version: $LATEST
['APPL']
loading data
Exception in thread Thread-1:
```

I ain't sure where I am going wrong. Any advice welcome Thanks

Comment: In your case the task timed out after 3 minutes. Did you try setting a higher timeout? Maybe the operations there take a bit more time?

Comment: the instructions say to set time out to 3 minutes. Im only collecting data for 1 ticker so don't expect it to take longer